# Proof that $(A-B)\cap C = (A\cap C)-B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A,B,$ and $C$. Prove that $(A-B)\cap C = (A\cap C)-B$.

Suppose $x\in (A-B)\cap C$, then $x$ is in $(A-B)$ and $C$. If $x\in (A-B)$ then $x\notin B$ but $x\in A$ hence $x\in A\cap C$, but not in $B$ which means $x\in (A\cap C)-B$ therefore $(A-B)\cap C \subset (A\cap C)-B$. Now suppose $y\in (A\cap C)-B$ then $y$ is in $A$ and $C$, but not in $B$ which is the same as $y\in (A-B)\cap (C-B)$, but $ (A-B)\cap (C-B) \subset (A-B)\cap C$ therefore $(A\cap C)-B \subset (A-B)\cap C$.

Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is correct, but the second half could be simplified: since $y\in A$, $y\in C$, you know that $y\in A\cap C$, and since furthermore $y\notin B$, you can immediately conclude that $y\in(A\cap C)\setminus B$.

Comment: I was thinking about doing it that way but for some reason I thought it will be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is correct, but it could be simplified using

$$X - Y = X \cap Y^c, \tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

where $Y^c$ is the complement of $Y$. I urge you to remember $(\spadesuit)$, it is usually very helpful with all kinds of problems with set difference. Then your formula

$$(A-B) \cap C = (A \cap C) - B$$
becomes

$$ (A\cap B^c) \cap C = (A \cap C) \cap B^c, $$

which is trivially true, because $\cap$ is commutative $X \cap Y = Y \cap X$
and associative $$(X \cap Y) \cap Z = X \cap (Y \cap Z).$$

Using this we conclude with

$$ (A\cap B^c) \cap C = A\cap (B^c \cap C) = A \cap (C \cap B^c) = (A \cap C) \cap B^c. $$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$